# Need Solaris network driver 64bit

Tags: networking, drivers, solaris

I'm newbie in Solaris and I need network driver 64bit for: -

```
pci bus 0x0004 cardnum 0x00 function 0x00: vendor 0x1186 device 0x4b01
 D-Link System Inc DGE-530T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 11)
  STATUS    0x02b0  COMMAND 0x0117
  CLASS     0x02 0x00 0x00  REVISION 0x11
  BIST      0x00  HEADER 0x00  LATENCY 0x40  CACHE 0x10
  BASE0     0xfe1fc000  addr 0xfe1fc000  MEM
  BASE1     0x0000dc01  addr 0x0000dc00  I/O
  BASEROM   0xfe200000  addr 0xfe200000  not-decode-enabled
  MAX_LAT   0x1f  MIN_GNT 0x17  INT_PIN 0x01  INT_LINE 0x0b
  BYTE_0    0x00  BYTE_1  0x00  BYTE_2  0xf0  BYTE_3  0x05
```

OS version: Sun OS 5.10 generic-137138-09(10/08)

I have found driver 32bit something called skgesol_x86v8.19.1.3 but it doesn't work. It asked me for the 64 version. Where I can find this driver?

Comment: Can you find out the card's chip? You may be able to get Solaris drivers at the chip manufacturer's site. Also the behavior is strange. I know that skge works fine in 64 bits, but it's questionable if that is the right driver for your card.

Comment: Read [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/constantin/entry/how_to_find_the_right) article. It's related to your card. Unfortunately, it seems that Marvell removed Solaris drivers from its website.

Comment: 88E8001-LKJ1 AK5LR.2. 0836 A4pTW these on the chip/ on the green broad DGE-530T REV-B2 8DGE530T.1B2G/ Do you have other ideas?Thank you again

Comment: As I said, the articel I linked to is related to your card. It used Marvell Yukon 88E8001 chip which is supported by the skge driver, but Marvell chose to remove it from its website. I can't give any better idea than to use Google and try to find the driver.